# CoreML - Multiarray input needs to be preprocessed in app or in model?

Tags: python, swift, audio, machine-learning, coreml

I have used this [library](https://github.com/drscotthawley/panotti) to build an audio classification model. Then I converted this model to CoreML. Later, I wanted to implement the model in this code https://github.com/robmsmt/kDS2iOS/

I have a problem with this as the input for the model is a Double MultiArray (1 x 96 x 435) and the code takes a different form. So I think I have two options one but please correct me if I'm wrong, I can do the recording in the app and do as the app is doing by preprocessing the audio file in the app making it appropriate for the model. The other option which I'm not sure if possible would be to make the original model accept audio so that I don't have to write the preprocessing code twice once in python and the other in xCode. Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what the preprocessing is. Core ML can do certain kinds of preprocessing (normalizing the input for example), but you'll still need to load your audio data into the MLMultiArray yourself (as Core ML does not have an "audio" input).

Comment: The preprocessing that is done in the first library is finding the maximum shape of the dataset then padding the ones with the shorter length. Then it adds layered of melgrams, and phase. I found one C library called aubio that is used in the currect xcode app but I'm wondering if there is any tutorial or some guide on this.